# Как лучше организовать данные?

Tags: ооп, php

Есть набор данных которые надо передать в генератор отчётов.
Генератор -- класс Report, строит отчёт по шаблону, особо не волнуясь о данных.
Данные -- класс ReportData, тянет данные из БД, проверяет их корректность.
Данных примерно 24 строки по ~24 поля каждая.
Как лучше организовать передачу данных?
Лично у меня два варианта:
Первый, формировать массив внутри ReportData и передавать его в Report.
Второй, формировать массив объектов ReportData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вам угодно, обычно модель возвращает массив данных (иногда просто массив, иногда объектов), а как вы с ними в контроллере поступите уже другой вопрос. Создайте класс ReportDate, который будет возвращать массив объектов, а можно даже и в нем же просто сделать метод, который будет обрабатывать (напр. выводить на печать) массив.